# What methods are called by Visual Studio Designer when it renders a WinForm?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

1. What methods are called by the Visual Studio Designer when it tries to render a WinForms class?
2. What happens when the Winforms class inherits from another WinForms class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after experimenting here's what I found:

1. If you are opening a form in a VS Designer that has a YourClass.Designer.cs file then:

   - the properties/fields defined in YourClass.Designer.cs will be new'ed
   - the "InitializeComponent()" method will be called

Note: Oddly, your constructor **WILL NOT** be called and you can prove this to yourself with something like the following (note, the Designer is fine with the following code):

```
public class YourClass ... {
   public YourClass() {
     throw new Exception("Ha (1)!");
     InitializeComponent();
     throw new Exception("Ha (2)!");
   }
}
```

2. If the class doesn't have a SomeControl.Designer.cs file or it is component within the class you are opening in the VS Designer then that component's constructor will be called. You can again test this with the above example.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens when the Winforms class inherits from another WinForms class?

In the past, I have used WinForm inheritance to force a standard layout between forms - sort of a master form. In design mode, any controls that are added to the parent form, will show in the child forms. You cannot edit the parent form directly from the child form designer.